# Dependency for String template in Apache Camel for fuse server Causes Class Cast Exception

Tags: apache-camel, stringtemplate, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I am using string template to generate html text and send it mail as attachement.

```
<route id="str-template"> 
    <from uri="activemq:queue:EDI.MSG.TEXT.MESSAGES" />
    <to uri="string-template:classpath:META-INF/spring/dataformat/stringTemplate/coparn-ack-txt.tm"/>
            //Here i am processing and the body contains the o/p of string-template component.
    <bean ref="generateCoparnAckMessage" method="processTextAckMessage" />
    <to uri="activemq:queue:EDI.SEND.AS.ATTACHMENT.MAIL.MESSAGES?mapJmsMessage=false" />
    //  It will be sent to mail camel component
</route>
```

Dependency was added as below. Also installed the camel-stringtemplate in fuse features using 
      features:install

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-stringtemplate</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.4</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The issue is it throws class cast exception

```
problem parsing template 'anonymous'
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.antlr.stringtemplate.language.ChunkToken cannot be cast to antlr.Token
    at antlr.CharScanner.makeToken(CharScanner.java:173)
    at org.antlr.stringtemplate.language.DefaultTemplateLexer.mINDENT(DefaultTemplateLexer.java:250)
    at org.antlr.stringtemplate.language.DefaultTemplateLexer.mLITERAL(DefaultTemplateLexer.java:196)
    at org.antlr.stringtemplate.language.DefaultTemplateLexer.nextToken(DefaultTemplateLexer.java:134)
    at antlr.TokenBuffer.fill(TokenBuffer.java:69)
    at antlr.TokenBuffer.LA(TokenBuffer.java:80)
    at antlr.LLkParser.LA(LLkParser.java:52)
    at org.antlr.stringtemplate.language.TemplateParser.template(TemplateParser.java:103)
    at org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplate.breakTemplateIntoChunks(StringTemplate.java:839)
    at org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplate.setTemplate(StringTemplate.java:441)
    at org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplate.<init>(StringTemplate.java:308)
    at org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplate.<init>(StringTemplate.java:293)
    at org.apache.camel.component.stringtemplate.StringTemplateEndpoint.onExchange(StringTemplateEndpoint.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProcessorEndpoint$1.process(ProcessorEndpoint.java:71)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2.doInAsyncProducer(SendProcessor.java:122)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:298)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:117)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)
    at org.apache.camel.fabric.FabricTraceProcessor.process(FabricTraceProcessor.java:81)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:334)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:220)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:46)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:308)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:117)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:46)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.processAsync(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:150)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.process(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:117)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.processNext(RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.java:48)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:99)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:86)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:104)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:562)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:500)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:468)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:326)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:264)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1071)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1063)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:960)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Kindly help.

Comment: You are using a non-standard distribution of StringTemplate, which may make it difficult to impossible for the StringTemplate authors to provide you with useful information here.

Comment: I am using ApacheCamel StringTemplate jar bcoz its required for String TemplateCamelCompontent in the route(Kindly see the camel route).